# MAX number from an inventory stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max

My database has these tables:

- Productos
- Productos_Presentaciones

This is an inventory and I want to know from all the products (productos), which one has more stock. So this is the last thing I could think of:

```
SELECT MAX(pp.Existencias), p.Nombre as PRODUCTO FROM Productos_Presentaciones pp
full join Productos p on pp.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
group by p.Nombre;
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

I just need to be shown a single result. In this case, the #9 from the image shown:

```
PRODUCTO                        EXISTENCIA
Carne de cangrejo de Boston        123
```

Which is the product with the most available stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Order by clause and limit for getting just one row

```
SELECT MAX(pp.Existencias) AS pex, p.Nombre as PRODUCTO FROM Productos_Presentaciones pp
FULL JOIN Productos p on pp.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
GROUP BY p.Nombre ORDER BY pex DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It worked! I just had to do some research, because I'm using MSSQL and it doesn't support LIMIT, so I removed it and added SELECT TOP 1 at the beginning. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I thought MySQL is your DB.